# How do I change the width of the default nsis buttons (next, cancel, etc..)

Tags: nsis

How do I change the width of the default buttons (next, cancel, etc..)
I want to increase the width of the button by 20 pixels, sounds easy but..

Let's say I have something like this:

```
# declare name of installer file
outfile "hello world.exe"

# open section
section

# create a popup box, with an OK button and some text
messageBox MB_OK "Now We are Creating Hello_world.txt at Desktop!"

/* open an output file called "Hello_world.txt", 
on the desktop in write mode. This file does not need to exist 
before script is compiled and run */

fileOpen $0 "$DESKTOP\Hello_world.txt" w

# write the string "hello world!" to the output file
fileWrite $0 "hello world!"

# close the file
fileClose $0
# Show Success message.
messageBox MB_OK "Hello_world.txt has been created successfully at Desktop!"


# end the section
sectionEnd
```

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This is the plugin you are looking for, may be.](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/NsResize_plug-in)

Answer (score 0):

The best way is probably to edit one of the files in ${NSISDIR}\Contrib\UIs with [Resource Hacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/) and then use `ChangeUI IDD_INST myui.exe` in your script.

The other alternative is to call user32::SetWindowPos at runtime with the system plugin...

Comment: How does user32::SetWindowPos helps achieving that?

Comment: GetDlgItem $0 $hwndparent 2 and System::Call 'USER32::SetWindowPos(i$0,i0,i0,i0,i100,i30,i0x1a)' in .onGuiInit but using ChangeUI is much better since you get to specify the size in dialog units...