# How to create/customize a web download installer like flash using nsis?

Tags: flash, installation, nsis

I want to create a web download installer using NSIS. I captured the following screenshots from installing flash, which is exactly what I want to create my own installer, which also downloading some files and then execute.

[image: Flash installing]

[image: Flash install interupt by press close button]

[image: Flash install complete]

I've tried NSIS modern UI and also the nsDialogs, but I find it is difficult for me to customize the pages looking like above. The issues I get here are,

1. How to resize the pages? I don't find a way to change the page size at will.
2. How to change the whole background to a color I want?
3. How to remove all the default buttons (back/next/cancel), but still need the top right close button work? I find if I hide the next or complete button, the close button will also be disabled.
4. How to customize the progress bar to indicate a reasonable progress on downloading and installing?
5. When install is ongoing, click the top right close button, how to show the warning message in current page instead of pop up a dialog?

As a NSIS beginner, I really appreciate your helps/suggestions/guidence.
Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think the titlebar close button cares if other buttons are hidden but it does care if you have been on the InstFiles page or not and if you are on the last page etc.

You can change the UI layout with the [ChangeUI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16678078) attribute. You can also do it at run-time:

```
Outfile "setup.exe"
Name "Wannabe UI"
Caption "$(^Name)"
RequestExecutionLevel user
XPStyle off
AutoCloseWindow true

!include nsDialogs.nsh
!include WinMessages.nsh
!include LogicLib.nsh
!define PBM_SETBARCOLOR 0x409
!define PBM_SETBKCOLOR 0x2001

!define CLRTXT ffffff
!define CLRBKG 353535

Page Custom mypagecreate
Page InstFiles

!macro SetPixelSize w h
System::Call 'USER32::SetWindowPos(i$hwndparent,i0,i0,i0,i${w},i${h},i0x1a)'
GetDlgItem $0 $hwndparent 0x3fa
System::Call 'USER32::SetWindowPos(i$0,i0,i0,i0,i${w},i${h},i0x10)'
!macroend
!macro DisableWindowClose disable
System::Call 'USER32::GetSystemMenu(i$hwndparent,i0)i.r0'
System::Call 'USER32::EnableMenuItem(ir0,i0xF060,i${disable})'
!macroend

var progbar
var progtxt
var button

Function mypagecreate
!insertmacro DisableWindowClose 1
!insertmacro SetPixelSize 400 200 
SetCtlColors $hwndparent 0x${CLRTXT} 0x${CLRBKG}
GetDlgItem $1 $hwndparent 1
ShowWindow $1 0
GetDlgItem $1 $hwndparent 2
ShowWindow $1 0
GetDlgItem $1 $hwndparent 0x404
ShowWindow $1 0
nsDialogs::Create 1018
Pop $0

${NSD_CreateLabel} 5% 13u 100% 10u "Some text here?"
Pop $0
SetCtlColors $0 0x${CLRTXT} 0x${CLRBKG}

${NSD_CreateProgressBar} 5% 25u 83% 10u ""
Pop $progbar
${NSD_AddStyle} $progbar 1 ;PBS_SMOOTH
SendMessage $progbar ${PBM_SETBARCOLOR} 0 0xee8888
SendMessage $progbar ${PBM_SETBKCOLOR} 0 0x${CLRBKG}

${NSD_CreateLabel} -27u 25u 19u 10u ""
Pop $progtxt
SetCtlColors $progtxt 0x${CLRTXT} 0x${CLRBKG}

${NSD_CreateButton} -60u -35u 50u 12u "&Close" 
Pop $button
ShowWindow $button 0
; NSIS cannot color a button, you have to use a plugin to do it, 
; or you could use a image...
;SetCtlColors $button 0x${CLRTXT} 0x${CLRBKG}
${NSD_OnClick} $button done

FindWindow $0 "#32770" "" $hwndparent ; Find inner dialog
SetCtlColors $0 0x${CLRTXT} 0x${CLRBKG}
${NSD_CreateTimer} emulatework 300
nsDialogs::Show
FunctionEnd

Function emulatework
SendMessage $progbar ${PBM_GETPOS} 0 0 $0
IntOp $0 $0 + 3
${If} $0 >= 100
    ${NSD_KillTimer} emulatework
    !insertmacro DisableWindowClose 0
    ShowWindow $button 1
    StrCpy $0 100
${EndIf}
SendMessage $progbar ${PBM_SETPOS} $0 0
${NSD_SetText} $progtxt "$0%"
FunctionEnd

Function done
SendMessage $hwndparent ${WM_CLOSE} 0 0
FunctionEnd

Section
SectionEnd
```

You have to use a plugin to download files, maybe [InetBgDL](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/InetBgDL_plug-in) would be a good fit for this type of UI...

Comment: Thanks Anders, your sample code works as I expected. I still have some more questions,
1. How to change the icon of the installer?
2. How does “Page Instfiles” work in this case?
3. Where should I put my downloading code? In the section part?
4. When I click the titlebar close button, how can I substitute my own implementation instead of closing directly?

Again, Thanks for your help.

Comment: Icon "myicon.ico", instfiles is not used, before nsDialogs::Show, not sure if that is possible...

Answer (score 0):

(1) it's probably best to use a [resource editor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_%28Windows%29#Resource_software), though i think there's a [plugin](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Category%3aPlugins) for nsis that let's you do that on runtime

(2-4) there are several plugins to change the appearance of an installer. take a look at [skinned control](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/SkinnedControls_plug-in), [skin-crafter](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/NSIS_SkinCrafter_Plugin_plug-in) or [skinned button](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/SkinnedButton_plug-in)

(5) use the [.onInstFailed](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html#) function